# get the number of youtube channel subscribers

Tags: asp.net, youtube-api

i need to get the number of subscribers of a youtube channel in my asp.net website, i have searched the documentation (https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_activity_feeds) and i got that i have to put this:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/PageName

but its not giving anything even when i open it in a browser it wont open any help would be much appreciated.

is there a special library or api i can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is the following:

```
System.Net.WebClient wb = new System.Net.WebClient();
string str = wb.DownloadString("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/TheNewYorkTimes");
Response.Write(getCount(str));

public static string getCount(string video)
        {
            if (video.Contains("="))
            {
                string str = "subscriberCount='";
                string videoid = video.Substring(video.IndexOf("subscriberCount") + str.Length);
                if (videoid.Contains("'"))
                {
                    videoid = videoid.Remove(videoid.IndexOf("'"));
                    return videoid;
                }
                else
                {
                    return "";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why use web-scrapping when there is API Available . More info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604742/how-to-get-subscriber-count-and-videos-count-for-a-given-youtube-channel