# How to get subscriber count and videos count for a given YouTube channel?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Until now I've been using this URL to retrieve subscriber count for a channel:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/<channel_id>?v=2&alt=json
```

And this URL to get channel videos count:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/<channel_id>/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=0
```

But from this day Google discontinued using it's v2 API and I can't find replacement options for this data.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're going to want to use the [Channels/list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) endpoint as pass in `statistics` for the `part` parameter.

Request:

```
HTTP GET: GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id={CHANNEL_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Response (with `id=UCt7iVnJwjBsof8IPLJHCTgQ`):

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"dhbhlDw5j8dK10GxeV_UG6RSReM/WNxXCvycTyqTjTn9sLJ5toVjBRY\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#channel",
   "etag": "\"dhbhlDw5j8dK10GxeV_UG6RSReM/jijTuA_iWn2Kv9aRnqeAWNAcQ6I\"",
   "id": "UCt7iVnJwjBsof8IPLJHCTgQ",
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "796662",
    "commentCount": "20",
    "subscriberCount": "257",
    "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
    "videoCount": "126"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

You can pass in a comma-separated list of Channel IDs for the `id` parameter.  Because I only passed in one `id`, the first object of the `items` array will have the values you need.  Get the object for the `subscriberCount` and `videoCount` values in the `statistics` dictionary for the data you want.

Comment: Is there any api without authentication?

Comment: @VivekSancheti there are no api without key