# Find Subscriber Count of YouTube Channel in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube, discord.js

I am making a very simple Discord bot that shows the subscriber count of a certain YouTuber.
I would like this to be automated so I don't have to change it all the time.

Here is my current code, which displays the subscriber count as the bot's status.
How do I get the channel's subscriber count through the website/YouTube API? (I am aware it will be abbreviated, that is fine).

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const {
  Client,
  MessageAttachment,
  MessageEmbed,
  MemberAdd,
  RichEmbed,
  message
} = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client();
client.on("ready", function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    var subcount
    subcount = "105M"
    client.user.setActivity(subcount + " subscribers" , {
      type: "STREAMING",
      url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"
    });
  }, 5000);
});

client.login("...");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get subscriber count and videos count for a given YouTube channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604742/how-to-get-subscriber-count-and-videos-count-for-a-given-youtube-channel)

Comment: is that your real token? If so change it quick.

Comment: Nope @Karizma. That was me hitting random keys. Thanks for the concern tho.

Comment: @I-portet - I don't really know how to integrate that into my code. Sorry I am new to these webhook things.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I translate, not async, a bunch of youtube channel urls into a pojo[] with 5 fields:

```
  public getRows() : RowData[] {
    console.log("Getting row data...");
    let tmpData: RowData[] = [];
    let promises : Promise<ChannelResponse>[] = [];
    for (let ch = 0; ch < this.channelUrls.length; ch++) {
      let tmp_promise = this.http.get<ChannelResponse>(this.channelUrls[ch].url).toPromise();
      promises.push(tmp_promise);
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then((valuesArray) => {
      //console.log('Response: ' + JSON.stringify(valuesArray));
      for (let i = 0; i < valuesArray.length; i++) {
        const item : Item = valuesArray[i].items[0];
        const channel : Channel = this.channelUrls[i];
        tmpData.push({
          channel: channel.name,
          id: channel.id,
          views: Number(item.statistics.viewCount),
          subscribers: Number(item.statistics.subscriberCount),
          videos: Number(item.statistics.videoCount)
        });
      }
    });
```

To make it work , you need this:

```
export interface RowData {
  channel: string;
  id: string;
  views: number;
  subscribers: number;
  videos: number;
}

export interface Channel {
  name: string;
  id: string;
  url: string;
}

export interface ChannelResponse {
  kind:     string;
  etag:     string;
  pageInfo: PageInfo;
  items:    Item[];
}

export interface Item {
  kind:       string;
  etag:       string;
  id:         string;
  statistics: Statistics;
}

export interface Statistics {
  viewCount:             string;
  subscriberCount:       string;
  hiddenSubscriberCount: boolean;
  videoCount:            string;
}

export interface PageInfo {
  totalResults:   number;
  resultsPerPage: number;
}
```