# How do I scrape a multiple YouTube channel's display name, creation date, and subscriber count?

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, youtube, youtube-channels

I am working on a project that scrapes multiple YouTube channels display name, creation date, subscriber count, and view count. I need help creating this project because I can't seem to find anything about it. I have a YouTube API Key and I just can't seem to find anything about this.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to work with the sample code that the YouTube api shows. Use the curl section. Then send a request to the link that shows and use the information. for example send http request to this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=[Channel ID]&key=[Your API]
```

and this address give you JSON file and you can get what you want!.
for example you can see subscribe count from channel list section in youtube api document. like this image.
[image]

you can find other things with this way!. good luck :)
also you can use [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604742/how-to-get-subscriber-count-and-videos-count-for-a-given-youtube-channel?rq=1)

Comment: I need a python program though

Answer (score 0):

i'm making sample for you.

```
def subscribeCount(channel_id):
    API = f"https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id={channel_id}&key=[Enter Your Api Key]"
    json_data = requests.get(API).json()
    subscribeCount = json_data['items'][0]['statistics']['subscriberCount']
    
    return subscribeCount
```

this sample need channel id(Like all other sections xD). and api key you Which you got from the google developer console.It then shows you the number of subscriptions to a channel. The rest of the sections work the same way.
Read the following article for more information.
[How to Use the Python Requests Module With REST APIs](https://www.nylas.com/blog/use-python-requests-module-rest-apis/)